# Create list from custom field comma separated values

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I've created a custom field named 'Essential Info', which I plan to allow the admin to add a list of values to. E.g.

No Pets
On-site doctor
Car Parking
100m from beach

...etc.

However, I'm not entirely sure how I can achieve this with custom fields. I was hoping that I could somehow allow the user to separate these values with a comma, and in the template tell it to output a separate list item everytime a value is separated by a comma.

At the moment, this is my code which obviously outputs whatever is in the custom field, but I need the admin to be able to add a list of values rather than a single line value:

```
<ul>
            <li><span>
            <?php if ( function_exists('get_custom_field_value') ){
                    get_custom_field_value('Essentials', true);
            } ?>
            </span></li>
        </ul>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($items as $item) { 

$item = nl2br($item);
list($name,$src,$price,$desc) = explode('<br />',$item); 

echo "<div class=\"item\">";
echo "<h2>$name</h2>";
echo "<img src=\"".trim($src)."\" />";
echo "<br />Price: $price";
echo "<br />Description: $desc";
echo "</div><br />"; 

}
```

This works if you have them hit enter after each value to make the list. http://vudu.me/f7 Is an article I wrote, and it has a link to my source, so you can get a better understanding of it

This would work best... I think... if you know how many values would be entered? You still need to open up by actually using get_post_meta of course....

Comment: I'm not sure if this actually solves the problem. The thing is, I only have one custom field, called Essentials, and the admin will be inputing a number of different fields separated by commas, or just by pressing ENTER as you suggested, but by the looks of your code, you already have a number of different variables set, and are simply adding a break-space between each one right? Apologies if I have misunderstood, as I'm not entirely familiar with PHP in Wordpress. I'm just a bit unsure how to apply what you have answered to my situation

Comment: well, what it does it take the values, and assign them in order to the variables in the list. 1st line goes to $name, 2nd line goes to $src, etc. Then we use those variables below. It would work best if you knew the max number of values which may be entered so you could use a variable for each... if you don't, I'm not sure exactly how to modify what I have above to allow for unlimited entries. That code doesn't add a break space, it breaks apart the list on a break space. It looks for a return